# binding breaks after screen rotation

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have exception "lateinit property binding has not been initialized" after screen rotation when I try call binding . How I can fix it ?

My base fragment code

```
    override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, contentLayoutID, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of initializing binding using `lateinit binding`, you should initialize it like that:

```
private var _binding: TypeOfBindingHere? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

And now your onCreateView should look like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
): View? {
    _binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, contentLayoutID, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the way Google demonstrates creating the reference to the binding class but does lateinit work differently somehow that this can throw the exception?
I'm fairly certain the lateinit was sampled by google docs at one point in using bindings, so it'd be nice to know how/why this resolves and prevents the crash?

Comment: Well if you use lateinit correctly it's not going to cause a crash but instead you will have the binding as var so you can change it by accident, also the binding is not going to be nullable and it's recommended to change it to null in `onDestroy` with `_binding = null`. This way we have a mutable `_binding` for initialization and for setting it null later and we have a safe val non nullable `binding` to use it